# ffi namespace not found after calling luaopen_ffi

Tags: c++, lua

I have a C++ program that creates will create a lua_State and invoke custom lua code.  Before calling the custom lua function, luaopen_ffi() is called with the lua_State:

```
luaopen_ffi(lua_state_);
```

However, when my program execute the custom lua code, it cannot find ffi.  I further print out the value of ffi, and sadly it's `nil` instead:

```
print(ffi)  --- which outputs nil
```

while other libraries loaded using luaopen does have a non-nil value, for instance

```
print(io)  --- outputs table: 0x400af268
```

I further checked the source code of [luaopen_ffi](http://agentzh.org/misc/code/luajit2/lib_ffi.c.html#L841), it says it does not create a global ffi namespace based on its comment:

```
LUALIB_API int luaopen_ffi(lua_State *L) {  
  CTState *cts = lj_ctype_init(L);
  settabV(L, L->top++, (cts->miscmap = lj_tab_new(L, 0, 1)));
  cts->finalizer = ffi_finalizer(L);
  LJ_LIB_REG(L, NULL, ffi_meta);
  /* NOBARRIER: basemt is a GC root. */
  setgcref(basemt_it(G(L), LJ_TCDATA), obj2gco(tabV(L->top-1)));
  LJ_LIB_REG(L, NULL, ffi_clib);
  LJ_LIB_REG(L, NULL, ffi_callback);
  /* NOBARRIER: the key is new and lj_tab_newkey() handles the barrier. */
  settabV(L, lj_tab_setstr(L, cts->miscmap, &cts->g->strempty), tabV(L->top-1));
  L->top--;
  lj_clib_default(L, tabV(L->top-1));  /* Create ffi.C default namespace. */
  lua_pushliteral(L, LJ_OS_NAME);
  lua_pushliteral(L, LJ_ARCH_NAME);
  LJ_LIB_REG(L, NULL, ffi);  /* Note: no global "ffi" created! */
  ffi_register_module(L);
  return 1;
}
```

I also tried `ffi = require("ffi")` and it does not work :(.

So can I know how can I use ffi features after calling luaopen_ffi?  Or luaopen_ffi is not the correct way?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the LuaJIT mailing list.

Comment: You tried `ffi = require("ffi")` with or without calling `luaopen_ffi` manually first? I would imagine it might not work after but without it should.

Comment: > You tried ffi = require("ffi") with or without calling luaopen_ffi manually first? ---

It does not work when I tried to call it from c++, but it works when I tried to use LuaJIT directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a global named `ffi`, try this:

```
luaopen_ffi(lua_state_);
lua_setglobal(lua_state_ ,"ffi");
```

It seems that `luaopen_ffi` leaves the table on the stack, as is usual in Lua modules.

Comment: This makes the "ffi" available.  However, I found I am not able to use normal ffi syntax such as ffi.cdef or use functions defined in ffi.C.  In addition, when I print out ffi.C or ffi.cdef, both of them show nil.  Can I know what I might do wrong?

Comment: Oops, I happen to remove luaopen_ffi when tried to add lua_setglobal.  Now when I have both luaopen_ffi and lua_setglobal, it works like charm.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I found the C functions that I would like to use in the lua script are not loaded into when my C++ program tries to run the lua script.  Is there anyway to make lua_State to preload necessary custom C functions / libraries so that they can be used via ffi.cdef[[ ]] and under ffi.C namespace?